# Accessing linker defined symbol in C

Tags: c, linker, extern, symbols

I have a linker symbol (let's call it __BASE_ADDR), defined in a linker command script, which contains the address of the longword *after* a longword that I need to use (e.g. I need to check longword at address 0x0000000C and __BASE_ADDR is equal to 0x00000010). So in the code I try to use __BASE_ADDR and subtract 4 from it to access 0x0000000C.

My linker map output correctly shows the value of __BASE_ADDR to be 0x00000010. However when I try to access the location using the following C code it doesn't work:

```
extern unsigned char *__BASE_ADDR;

void someFunc( void )
{
    unsigned long Val = *((unsigned long *) (__BASE_ADDR - 4));

    /* Use Val for some comparison...*/
    /* ... */
}
```

Val gets set to the wrong value. What appears to be happening is that whatever longword is at __BASE_ADDR is taken as an address, 4 is subtracted, and the contents of the resulting address is put into Val.

But when I do the following, it does work fine and Val is set correctly to whatever resides at address 0x0000000C:

```
extern unsigned char __BASE_ADDR[];

void someFunc( void )
{
    unsigned long Val = *((unsigned long *) (__BASE_ADDR - 4));

    /* Use Val for some comparison...*/
    /* ... */
}
```

Can anyone shed light on this? I understand why you can't access a linker symbol's contents (it technically has no contents), but why would there be a difference between accessing the linker symbol as a pointer and accessing it as an array?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> (e.g. I need to check longword at address `0x0000000C` and `__BASE_ADDR` is equal to `0x00000010`)

The symptoms say that `0x00000010` is not the *value* of `__BASE_ADDR`, but the *address*.

So

```
unsigned long Val = *((unsigned long *) (__BASE_ADDR - 4));
```

does indeed read the value at `0x00000010` (obtaining the value of `__BASE_ADDR`), subtracts four from it and interprets the result as the address of the `unsigned long` to store in `val`.

With

```
extern unsigned char __BASE_ADDR[];
```

the address of the array `__BASEADDR` is the same as the address of the array's first element, so in that case,

```
unsigned long Val = *((unsigned long *) (__BASE_ADDR - 4));
```

- converts the array name `__BASE_ADDR` to a pointer to its first element, and the address that results in is the address of `__BASE_ADDR` (just a different type), `0x00000010`;
- then 4 is subtracted from that `unsigned char*`, resulting in the address `0x0000000C`;
- then that address is cast to `unsigned long*`, dereferenced and the value located there stored in `val`.

(The last point very probably invokes undefined behaviour, but you *may* be in a situation where you know it works, if you deal with fixed addresses.)

Comment: My bad, that was actually a typo - the extern is actually a char in the code!

Comment: Changed the answer to address the current situation.

Comment: Your guess was correct, linker symbols are in fact names of an address. So when you write X = 5 in a linker file, you're really saying X is the name of address 5. As such, in C code, if you want to extract the value 5 from X, you must declare X as something that conforms to those semantics.